# Kerberos authentication for restheart mongo client server

Tags: mongodb, kerberos, restheart

How to pass in kerberos token for authentication to kerborized mongo cluster through restheart? Should I do some custom implementation?

FYI Kerberos Authentication works fine when I use native mongo client in java/scala.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current RESTHeart version 1.0.3 does not support Kerberos authentication.

However if you get the latest development version from github, it allows defining the MongoDB connection via a [connection URI](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/).

This should allow to use Kerberos authentication. However I haven't tried it yet.

The new configuration option is called **mongo-uri**.